# NIB in bundle is missing with name MainWindow-iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, nib

I have a Tab bar application having 6 tabs. When I debug and runthe app, it crashes by giving following message in console :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/priyachaturvedi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/7C5CE523-A843-443A-9B0B-BDF2336EA7D0/Aljex Mobile-iPad.app> (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow-iPad''
```

I have already searched out the answersin the following links

[How to fix iPhone Simulator trying to launch a Nib that isn't there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148074/how-to-fix-iphone-simulator-trying-to-launch-a-nib-that-isnt-there)

[How are XIBs loaded for localized apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988589/how-are-xibs-loaded-for-localized-apps)

and

[Could not load NIB in bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827949/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle)

and many other but nothing worked for me.

any one have any idea why this is happening to me???

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: check if this file is present in the copy bundle resources in your target

Comment: I think mismatch of names in plist (MainWindow-ipad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you already checked filenames and so on. So I exclude hypothesis of filenames mismatch. Where might be a problem? You might by mistake excluded MainWindow-iPad.xib from being copied into your app during build (linking) time. How to check that?

1. Insure MainWindow-iPad.xib is in your project.
2. In project in section Products select your app and in context menu choose Show in Finder. In Finder in context menu choose Show Package Contents. Ensure your MainWindow-iPad.xib is there. If it isn't there, go to step 3. If MainWindow-iPad.xib is in package, double check file names, the problem seems to be in filenames mismatch.
3. If it isn't there find MainWindow-iPad.xib in your project, select it and ensure checkbox of your target in Inspector isn't deselected. You might did that by mistake. Check this checkbox and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too. I realise that when you enter the name of the xib file, it has to be "MainWindow-ipad" without the xib extension in your app targ